# how to get back the "payload" of the button " Get Started " in c#

Tags: c#, botframework

I work with Microsoft Bot Framework in Messenger and I would like to know how to get back the "payload" of the "Get Started" button. Which function I should create in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to - the payload is returned as a regular message, so you can just use this:

```
if (activity.ChannelId == "facebook" && activity.Text == "GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD")
{
   // etc
```

Note that the [documentation lists some restrictions on this feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/get-started-button):

> - The welcome screen is only shown the first time the user interacts with the Page on Messenger.
> - Only admins, developers, and testers of the app can see it when the app is in development mode.
> - Your app must be subscribed to postback webook events.

Comment: In my function public async TaskHttpResponseMessage > Post([FromBody] Activity message) I does not receive the "GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD" it does not work

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The above code is in Production and working though. If you send a `GET` request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=get_started&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN does it return your payload?

Comment: Yes i receive that : {
   "data": [
      {
         "get_started": {
            "payload": "GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
         }
      }
   ]
}

Comment: In that case it's setup correctly. It's only sent for a new user, of course, though deleting the conversation archive in Messenger should enable the "Get Started" button for testing. See edited answer for more.

Comment: I already delete the conversation before testing... WHat do you mean by "edited answer" ?

Comment: I edited my answer to list the feature restrictions from the documentation

Comment: the feature restrictions from the documentation "Greeting text" not for "Get started". My problem is that I arrive has to get back the event of " Get started ", when the user click on the button, I have the impression that the activity does not pass in my function "public async TaskHttpResponseMessage > Post([FromBody] Activity message)"